# Why doesn't map! with an if work like I expect?

Tags: ruby

When I run the following code:

```
range = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
range.each {|z| print z, " "}
puts "\n"
range.map! {|y| y /= 3 if y % 3 == 0}
range.each {|z| print z, " "}
```

I get the following output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
nil 1 nil nil 2 nil nil 3 nil
```

Whereas I'm expecting the second line of output to contain:

```
2 1 4 5 2 7 8 3 10
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the way the `map` operator and how its associated code block is supposed to work?

Note: I'm learning Ruby after programming extensively in C/C++ for a number of years, and this is the smallest snippet of a non-working Ruby program that I've been stuck in. If required, I can paste the original program out of which I constructed this MWE as well.

Answer (score 7):

`y /= 3 if y % 3 == 0` is a whole expression on its own.  When the conditional part evaluates to false, the entire expression evaluates to `nil`. `map!` is modifying the array in-place and it doesn't care if the resulting elements are numbers or `nil`.

One way to rewrite that to get the desired output would be:

```
range.map! {|y| y % 3 == 0 ? y / 3 : y}
```

Comment: How would you go about changing the program then?

Answer (score 3):

Replace with this:

```
range.map! {|y| y % 3 == 0 ? y / 3 : y}
```

`map` uses the value you *returned* from the block. There is no point in altering temporary `y` variable.

Comment: What if the block is a *do - end* complex set of instructions - would map then store the value of the last expression evaluated, similar to how values are returned from methods?

Comment: Yes, the last expression's value is used.

Comment: You can also use `next obj` to "return" `obj` from a block. Essentially `next` is the `return` of blocks. (Note that lambda's behave slightly differently again as they are more functions in the traditional sense)

Comment: @azgult: Rule of thumb: lambdas behave like methods, procs behave like blocks.